# pandas merging 300 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

The purpose of this code is

1. Scrape a 300 of tables via Pandas and Beautiful Soup
2. Concatenate this tables into a single data frame
   The code works fine for the first step. But it is not working in the second.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 " "Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\links.txt").readlines()

for site in url:
    req = Request(site, headers=header)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table')
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Release Date', 'Time']}, index_col=[0])[0]
    df = pd.concat(df, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
    print(df)
```

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/try.py", line 18, in

```
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
```

File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 225, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)

File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 241, in **init**

```
'"{name}"'.format(name=type(objs).__name__))
```

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pandas concat function takes a *sequence or mapping of Series, DataFrame, or Panel objects* as it's first argument. Your code is currently passing a single DataFrame.

I suspect the following will fix your issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 " "Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\links.txt").readlines()

dfs = []

for site in url:
    req = Request(site, headers=header)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table')
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Release Date', 'Time']}, index_col=[0])[0]
    dataframes.append(df)

concat_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
print(df)
```

All I have done is to create a list called *dfs*, as a place to append your DataFrames as you iterate through the sites. Then *dfs* is passed as the argument to concat.

Comment: thanks man for the help, yet the code raise another error and it is date related 
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'